# format .csv data created with fputcsv into Excel-like tables

Tags: php, mysql

is there a way that I can format data from a .csv file created with the php function fputcsv into Excel-like tables? Meaning, I don't want my data to be separated by commas, I want them to appear in tables like an Excel spreadsheet or something.

I know I can do that in Excel itself, but is there a way to do that directly without tweaking the file in Excel (like with a php function or something)

Comment: add some more info about format in which you are trying to convert the csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`fputcsv`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) does exactly what [the manual says](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php):
It formats a line as CSV and writes it to a file pointer.

The output can then be imported into Excel or other csv-capable software.

You can generate Excel files directly via php, too, but therefore you have to delve very deep into the Excel file format. If you want to do this, I recommend [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/). This project provides...

> ...a set of classes for the PHP programming language, which allow you to
> write to and read from different file formats, like Excel 2007, PDF,
> HTML, ... This project is built around Microsoft's OpenXML standard
> and PHP.